# Copy/Mirror traffic to WAN interfaces without “iptables tee” support

Tags: iptables, embedded, routing, mirror

I want to copy every outgoing packet to other WAN interfaces but my `iptables` (v1.2.7) doesn't have TEE target support. I wonder if there is another way (maybe using `iproute2` or `ebtables`) to copy every outgoing packet to an selected interface.

I prefer another way than getting xtables-addons because I'm working with a embedded device (an UClinux distribution) and I would prefer avoid new versions of `iptables` (I don't know if the syntax remains the same among versions), cross-compiling problems or changing Makefiles.

Comment: Is this for a one off or a permanent solution on multiple devices?

Comment: this solution can be disabled at running time, its not permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Found this Q&A on ServerFault titled: [Copy/Mirror traffic to WAN interfaces without “iptables tee” support](https://serverfault.com/questions/522209/copy-mirror-traffic-to-wan-interfaces-without-iptables-tee-support). It looks like you have 2 options:

1. Use the  [ROUTE target from patch-o-matic](http://www.mail-archive.com/netfilter-devel@lists.samba.org/msg01285.html) which does have a `--tee` option for `iptables`.
2. Use libpcap to do the mirroring - [libpcap-based port-mirroring project](http://code.google.com/p/port-mirroring/) .

Comment: I was working with dial on demmand ppp interfaces and the purpose was to awake all ppp interfaces when there was outgoing traffic. Finally i solve this issue by changing pppd code.